# Plotly - second figure overwriting first figure

Tags: plotly

I have the following Python 3.6 code.  When I run the code as one program (in Spyder IDE), I get two figures in two different tabs in my browser as I should. However, both the tabs are showing fig2. When I run the code for fig1 and fig2 separately (manually), then I get fig1 and fig2 in the two tabs correctly. It seems that when I run the whole program in one go, the second figure somehow overwrites the first figure. Not sure what is wrong. How can I rectify this ? Many Thanks !

This is the data from the csv file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkMbX.png)

[image]

```
import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.plotly as py
import pandas as pd
from plotly import tools

filepath = r'C:\Data'
ethnicity = pd.read_csv(filepath+'/Ethnicity.csv', header=None, names=['number'])

#chart 1
pietrace1 = {'type':'pie',
        'labels':ethnicity.index.tolist(),
        'values':ethnicity.number,
        'direction':'clockwise'
        }
data1 = [pietrace1]
layout1 = {'title':'Ethnicity of students',
      'xaxis':{'title':'Ethnicity'} ,
      'yaxis':{'title':'Number'}
      }
fig1 = go.Figure(data=data1, layout=layout1)
pyo.plot(fig1)

#chart 2
colors = ['rgb(12,192,170)',
      'rgb(190,252,250)',
      'rgb(77194,84)',
      'rgb(211,238,128)',
      'rgb(97,167,193)'
      ]
pietrace2 = {'type':'pie',
        'labels':ethnicity.index.tolist(),
        'values':ethnicity.number,
        'direction':'clockwise',
        'marker':{'colors':colors, 'line':{'width':1, 'color':'white'}} 
        }
data2 = [pietrace2]
layout2 = {'title':'Ethnicity of students',
      'xaxis':{'title':'Ethnicity'} ,
      'yaxis':{'title':'Number'}
      }
fig2 = go.Figure(data=data2, layout=layout2)
pyo.plot(fig2)
```

Comment: Try to specify `filename`: that's migth prevent plotly to overwrite plot in html file. Such as: `pyo.plot(fig, filename='plot1.html')` and `py.iplot(fig, filename='plot2.html')`

Comment: Does `fig1.show()` and `fig2.show()` not work (if you replaced the `pyo.plot()` calls)?

Answer (score 0):

I not sure about the exact technical explanation but I believe the rendering of the plots in your browser and the execution of python code happen simultaneously. Sometimes this leads to conflicts when the first plot is being rendered but the code for the second plot is already being executed, leading to overlap.

What worked for me was adding a small `time.sleep(2)` pause to give the first plot enough time to be fully rendered. You might play around with the length of the pauser depending on your PC performance

So in your case you could add:

```
.
.
.
fig1 = go.Figure(data=data1, layout=layout1)
pyo.plot(fig1)

time.sleep(2) # add pause for rendering

#chart 2
colors = ['rgb(12,192,170)',
      'rgb(190,252,250)',
      'rgb(77194,84)',
      'rgb(211,238,128)',
      'rgb(97,167,193)'
      ]
.
.
.
```